# Can I view the command line equivalents of the actions I perform on a computer?

Tags: operating-system

For example, when I click a file, or type a URL, the operating system is executing some code. I want to view this in real time.

**Edited**

I want to be able to replicate the action with just code rather than mouse clicking and keyboard pressing.

Comment: Are you talking about the entire operating system (which?) or just the shell/window manager?  Who's to say every action has a command line equivalent?  Also, "view[ing] this (executing some code) in real time" and viewing the command line equivalent of that code are not the same thing.

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews thank you for that. I'm not sure which one is more relevant to the action but will you point me to any please? How to see real time code for I take - I suppose even if I get it with some lag, I want to be able to replicate the action with just code rather than mouse clicking and keyboard pressing.

Comment: You'd need some kind of debugger or driver to capture those calls.  For example, Process Monitor on Windows is able to log filesystem, registry, network, and process events with call stacks.  As far as correlating those to higher-level user actions and getting some kind of command line for it, I wouldn't hold out much hope for that.  Again, it would depend on the operating system and I think much of it would be application-specific.  What are you _really_ trying to do?  There's programs that are able to automate mouse and keyboard events.